# recurrence relation discrete mathematics homework

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the recurrence relation: $a_{n} = c_{1} a_{n-1} + c_{2} a_{n-2} + c_{3} a_{n-3} $ for $n \geq 3$. Suppose that $x_{0}$, $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are the roots from the characteristic equation: $x^{3} - c_{1} x^{2} - c_{2} x - c_{3} = 0 $. Prove (without using a theory) that $a_{n} = nx_{0}^{n} $ is a solution from this recurrence relation if and only if $x_{0}$ is a multiple zero from the characteristic equation (so $x_{1} = x_{0}$ and/or $x_{2} = x_{0}$)

Answer (score 0):

True only if $x_0\neq 0$, replace $a_3$ in the equation so you get :
$$3x_0^3=2c_1x_0^2+c_2x_0 $$
But $x_0\neq 0$ so $3x_0^2=c_1x_0+c_2$ which means that $x_0$ is a zero of the derivative of the characteristic polynomial, so it's a multiple zero of it.